# In Angular For Every Error on Html and TS and Module Error it is showing same error Details

Tags: angular, zone.js

in Angular Project i am using Angular 5 with .Net MVC.  for Ts error, Module Level Error and Even for HTML syntax error also it is Displaying same error. its getting Difficult to Handle. please Help me.

```
TypeError: exceptionHandler.handleError is not a function
at Object.next (core.js:5493)
at SafeSubscriber.schedulerFn [as _next] (core.js:4327`enter code here`)
at SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub (Subscriber.js:239)
at SafeSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:186)
at Subscriber._next (Subscriber.js:126)
at Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:90)
at EventEmitter.Subject.next (Subject.js:55)
at EventEmitter.emit (core.js:4307)
at core.js:4767
at ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:388)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems you have custom exception handler in your code.
1. In case its not really required remove from code.

```
import { ErrorHandler } from '@angular/core';
```

remove this import and dependent code from your project.

2. In case its required then, double check the exception handler class

   ```
   import { ErrorHandler } from '@angular/core';

   export default class MyErrorHandler implements ErrorHandler {
       constructor() { 

           super(true);
       }

       handleError(error) {

           super.handleError(error); 
       }
   }






   import { NgModule, ErrorHandler } from '@angular/core';
   import MyErrorHandler from './my-error-handler';

   @NgModule({
           imports: [ BrowserModule ],
           declarations: [ App ],
           providers: [ { provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: MyErrorHandler } ]
           bootstrap: [ App ]
   })
   export class AppModule {}
   ```

Answer (score 0):

1. Check if you re-assigned global exception handler in your angular project like in thi article https://medium.com/@amcdnl/global-error-handling-with-angular2-6b992bdfb59c.
   And fix it or turn it off.
   Search the project for 'handleError'.
2. Check same for JS level https://www.tutorialspoint.com/How-to-write-a-global-error-handler-in-JavaScript